# Cyberpunk story where the protagonist gets his equipment shipped from Uzbekistan

Tags: story-identification

This is on the tip of my tongue, but I just can't quite pull it in.

I recall a specific small scene in a cyberpunk work (I don't know if it was a novel or a shorter work).  The protagonist, who is either on the run or trying to sneak up on someone (and so similarly keeping a low profile) has a whole bunch of equipment shipped to a hotel he's staying in.  Most of the equipment is black-market stuff shipped from Uzbekistan.  The protagonist has a conversation about it with the manager or proprietor of the hotel (mostly paraphrased):

> "That's a lot of stuff."
>
> "It's gifts from my friends."
>
> "You have a lot of friends in Uzbekistan?"
>
> "The Uzbeks are a very generous people."

(That last line is about 90% exact.)

I thought it was from something by Gibson, but I checked the *Sprawl Trilogy*, *Burning Chrome* and the *Blue Ant Trilogy* with no luck.  I've also checked a few other works, like *Snowcrash* where I thought the plot might vaguely fit, but I'm just not finding it.  (And google books gave me no matches at all.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

...Aand I'm an idiot, or at least my brain is made of swiss cheese.  (But you probably noticed that already.)

I was so hung up on it being Gibson that the only book by Walter Jon Williams I thought of was *Hardwired*, which of course is not it.  But it *is* [*Voice of the Whirlwind*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?918), the semi-sequel to *Hardwired*.  I was wrong about a hotel, since I was fixated on it having an Earth locale; Steward is arriving onboard a ship:

> Cairo looked at him sidelong. "There's **a lot of stuff** waiting for you in your rack. All your mail. A bagful."
>
> "All my **friends** on Earth **sending me presents**, I guess."
>
> "Do most of **your friends live in Uzbekistan**? I couldn't help but notice the postmarks."
>
> Steward shrugged. "**The Uzbeks are a generous people**." He began following the cargo into the ship's hold.

Comment: How did I finally find it?  I started looking through a [list of cyberpunk works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cyberpunk_works) to see what I might have missed.